# Can I create a network (sharing) password that's different from my login credentials?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking

**Let ms start by providing some context/background...**

When using a local account on Windows 10, one can set whatever password they like and it will be used for sharing as well. When using a Microsoft account, one is stuck with the Microsoft password.

Now, this is a security risk, in my opinion, because sometimes I might want to access my files from a device that I'm not willing to share my Microsoft account password with (e.g., an Android application).

So, I'm wondering if there's an option to set a password just for network sharing. **Does such option exist?**

**Alternatives that I'm aware of:**

- Abandon the Microsoft Account integration altogether and use a local account.
  <sub>(This is not a good alternative because I don't want to lose the sync between devices.)</sub>
- Create a separate local administrator account and use its login credentials for network sharing.
  <sub>(I would like to avoid having a dummy user account with its own files and settings dedicated solely for the purpose of sharing (if possible), so this will be my last resort if there's no better option.</sub>

Comment: Can't you just reset your password?

Comment: @WasifHasan I'm not sure what you mean. Suppose I want to access my shared files from an Android application (and want to keep the connection) but I don't trust that application with Microsoft account password. What exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: I was saying to change your local and Microsoft account password.

Comment: The way you put your question, the best alternative is a separate user account. If you do this, your files must be in a neutral location, not USERS.

Comment: @John Actually, files under the "Users" directory will still be accessible as long as the user is administrator. I was just hoping someone might know a better option.

Comment: Normally administrator1 cannot access the user files of administrator2. Windows 10 is very secure this way.

Comment: @John You made me doubt my memory. I just tried it and it _is_ accessible. I believe that's because the default permissions for `Administrators` [are set to Full Control](https://i.imgur.com/0uaWsOj.png).